# c# how to initialize or set a default constructor value to a injected dependency from class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a class that uses dependency injection:

```
public class MainClass: IDisposable
    {

        IUtilityRepository _utilityRepo = null;

        public MainClass()
        {

        }

        public MainClass(IUtilityRepository utilityRepo)
        {

            _utilityRepo = utilityRepo;

        }
}
```

Then my UtilityRepository class has:

```
 public class UtilityRepository : IUtilityRepository
    {
        private int _userId;
        private int _sessionId;

        // maybe have here some constructor where i can get some values from MainClass
       public  UtilityRepository ()
       {
          // here set the private properties from the MainClass when the dependency is intialized from MainClass
       }


        public List<string> MethodTestOne(string tempFolder)
        {
// here I want to 
        }

public List<string> MethodTestTwo(string tempFolder)
        {
        }
}
```

What I want to do is to pass from `MainClass` two properties to `UtilityRepository` class so any method within `UtilityRepository` can use those values globaly in the class without the need of passing the values to every method in a independant way.

> Any clue?

Comment: If (?) I understand correctly: Do you want to inject `IUtilityRepository` into `MainClass` while simultaneously injecting something from `MainClass` into `UtilityRepository`? If so, you can't. You could have the container independently inject into `UtilityRepository`. One reason is that `MainClass` depends on an abstraction, an interface. It doesn't know that the implementation of that interface even has dependencies. It's not supposed to know that. So it can't provide those dependencies.

Comment: Ok, so if I want to inject data from MainClass into UtilityRepository I will have to create like public properties in UtilityRepository class and then set those in the MainClass constructor right? By doing that can I have that property values accessible correct?

Comment: No. The point of injecting an interface into `MainClass` is that `MainClass` doesn't know anything about any concrete implementation of that interface. If `MainClass` passes anything to the implementation, that means it knows what the implementation is, and now `MainClass` is coupled to the implementation. How does `MainClass` get those values? Can you just have `UtilityRepository` depend on something and inject the values directly into it?

Comment: Another question: Does `MainClass` use those values at all, or does it only have them so it can pass them to another class? If `MainClass` needs them it should have them. If it doesn't actually need them - only `UtilityRepository` needs them - then `MainClass` shouldn't have them at all. You can just inject them directly where they're actually needed.

Comment: UtilityRepository has a lot of methods where I need UserID and SessionID properties. This properties are in MainClass or other classes that will inject UtilityRepository. So I want to avoid passing UserId and SessionID for every method that I have in UtilityRepository. I want a way I can set those values when UtilityRepository is being initialized and that those values persist across any method call from within MainClass or other class.

Comment: Sometimes it's ok to impose requirements on the implementations. For example, the constructor must receive userId and sessionId parameters. So the MainClass still isn't aware of any concrete implementation, but it relies on the abstract specification  that defines these two parameters.

Comment: @felix - true, but the idea is to avoid that as much as possible. What if `MainClass` is a class created by some other class? Now that class will have to pass those args to `MainClass` so that `MainClass` can pass them to `UtilityRepository`. If at all possible - and it usually is - we don't want a class to know about the dependencies of their dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: We should inject dependencies into the classes that need them. Classes shouldn't be responsible for providing dependencies to their dependencies.

If `MainClass` receives `userId` and `sessionId` from somewhere, how does it receive them? Presumably they are injected into `MainClass`, or something that provides them is injected.

If `MainClass` receives them via injection, `UtilityRepository` can receive them the same way. If `MainClass` doesn't receive them via injection, configure your container to inject them into `UtilityRepository` anyway. That could look like this:

```
public interface IContext // not the greatest name
{
    string UserId { get; }
    string SessionId { get; }
}
```

or

```
public interface IContextAccessor
{
    // where Context is an object containing the values you need.
    Context GetContext();
}
```

Then you configure the container provide a runtime implementation of `IContextAccessor` that retrieves the values from the current request. Inject `IContextAccessor` into `UtilityRepository`.

```
public class UtilityRepository : IUtilityRepository
{
    private readonly IContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public UtilityRepository(IContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
}
```

If `MainClass` doesn't need those values (it was only receiving them so it could pass them to something else) then it shouldn't receive them. If `MainClass` *does* need them, the fact that `UtilityRepository` also needs them is coincidental. (You can inject `IContextAccessor` into `MainClass` too.) There's no reason why `MainClass` needs to be responsible for passing them to `UtilityRepository`.

`MainClass` depends on an abstraction - `IUtilityRepository`. It does not and should not know what the concrete implementation of that interface depends on. It shouldn't know anything at all that isn't in that interface. As soon as it does, it no longer "depends" on the interface. It's coupled to the implementation.

That's one of the primary benefits of using an IoC container. Classes get their dependencies from the container, not from each other. Depending on abstractions means that classes don't know how those abstractions are implemented. That in turn means that classes don't know about the the dependencies *of* their dependencies.

---

To illustrate: A lamp depends on an abstraction - a power outlet that gets its power from *somewhere.* It could a be a power grid, a solar panel, a generator, a bicycle, or anything else.

Whatever the *implementation* of the power source is, it probably has dependencies of its own. A generator needs gasoline. A power grid needs a power plant.

Those dependencies probably have dependencies of their own. A power plant needs someone to shovel coal.

The lamp shouldn't know anything about those dependencies. If using a lamp means:

- Plug in the lamp
- Turn on the lamp
- Put gas in the generator

Then we're no longer depending on an abstraction. We're depending on a generator. It doesn't matter if we declare it as an interface and call it `IPowerSupply`. The only implementation it can work with is a generator.

The same goes for the power grid. It depends on a power source. That power source might require coal, generators, etc. But what happens if we make the power grid responsible for starting the generator, and then later we want to replace the generator with a massive solar panel array? How will the power grid start the generator when there is no generator?

That's why every class should know as little as possible about its dependencies. If it knows something, it's coupled to that detail. The whole point of Dependency Inversion (depending on abstractions) is to prevent or minimize coupling so that changing one implementation detail doesn't have a ripple effect that forces us to change other things that shouldn't have to change.

IoC containers make it super easy for us to accomplish that. Every class says what it needs by requiring it in the constructor, and the container injects it. If the thing injected has its own dependencies, the container takes care of that too. All of our classes get constructed independently without knowing anything about each other.

Comment: What I did now was to create a public property in UtilityRepository then have that same in my IUtilityRepository interface and from MainClass in the constructor I set the property value, but once I call a method like _utilityRepo.MethodTestOne and I try to get the property value, the value is zero. Its not persistant.

Comment: MainClass get those values from the current user session. So those values are not injected into MainClass. Now, what I dont get is how do I set this values from MainClass to the IContext interface that you have?

Comment: That will work, but I don't recommend it. `IUtilityRepository` should be an abstraction, not a mirror image of a concrete implementation. If the implementation depends on something and you have to go back and change the abstraction to reflect that, then it's no longer really an abstraction. If an interface can only represent one class, it's not an abstraction. https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/02/Interfacesarenotabstractions/.

Comment: Scott appreciate so much your amazing explanation very good!!... I still dont know how the interface IContext should be implemented in MainClass so UtilityRepository can get those properties. Appreciate so much your help

Comment: That's actually the great thing about it. It helps you to solve one problem at a time. You can write the classes that depend on an interface, and then look at implementing the interface as a completely separate problem. The runtime implementation could be a class that depends on `IHttpContextAccessor`, or, in older technologies, `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Scott how can I set userId and sessionId values from MainClass?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, passing parameters to constructor of an implementation introduces coupling which is the opposite of the dependency injection principle.

However, if you define a requirement that every implementation must receive the two parameters `userId` and `sessionId` in constructor, the decoupling is preserved, since all implementations adhere to this convention.

To enable such a scenario, `MainClass` must receive `IKernel` parameter, rather than `IUtilityRepository`:

```cs
public class MainClass
{
    private readonly IUtilityRepository _utilityRepo = null;

    public MainClass()
    {
    }

    public MainClass(IKernel kernel)
    {
        var userId = new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument("userId", 123);
        var sessionId = new Ninject.Parameters.ConstructorArgument("sessionId", 456);

        _utilityRepo = kernel.Get<IUtilityRepository>(userId, sessionId);
    }
}
```

In this way `UtilityRepository` will be able to receive the two parameters in the constructor:

```cs
public class UtilityRepository : IUtilityRepository
{
    private readonly int _userId;
    private readonly int _sessionId;

    // maybe have here some constructor where i can get some values from MainClass
    public  UtilityRepository (int userId, int sessionId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
        _sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public List<string> MethodTestOne(string tempFolder)
    {
        // do something...
    }

    public List<string> MethodTestTwo(string tempFolder)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Note that in such a case, the registration of `UtilityRepository` must be transient, so that a new instance is created every time it's requested with the specific parameter values:

```cs
kernel.Bind<IUtilityRepository>().To<UtilityRepository>().InTransientScope();
```

One downside of this solution is that `MainClass` doesn't use constructor parameters any longer in order to explicitly declare its dependencies. The code is now less self-documenting.

Comment: This looks like a service locator. The class depends directly on the container and resolves dependencies from it. Instead `MainClass` should just be resolved from the container, and whatever it depends on, the container will inject it.

Comment: @ScottHannen I agree that this design is less than ideal, yet I want to demonstrate the technique that OP asked about. You proposed a cleaner design, which can be a good choice if it's possible for OP to implement.

Comment: Ok, so basically is that better that I avoid that correct? So is better to pass those parameters to every method as Im doing right now instead of setting those globally in the UtilityRepository?

Comment: It's better to implement solution suggested in @ScottHannen's answer. If you cannot, then implement mine. Passing these values to every method doesn't seem to be a good idea.